# React Relay Uncaught Error: GraphQL validation error ``Cannot query field "clientList" on type "Query".

Tags: javascript, graphql, relayjs, relay, graphql-js

I've made one query for the main page and it works perfect but when I try to do another relay query to /clients page then relay does not see new type that I've added to the server. This is pretty weird because when I run update-schema the type is present on schema.graphql and when I try to query it with graphiql it works as well.

The error I get:

> Uncaught Error: GraphQL validation error `Cannot query field
>   "clientList" on type "Query". Did you mean "countryList"?` in file
>   `/home/robert/Sites/relay-test/src/queries/ClientQuery.js`. Try
>   updating your GraphQL schema if an argument/field/type was recently
>   added

**ClientQuery.js**

```
import Relay from 'react-relay';

export default {
    clientList: () => Relay.QL`query { clientList }`,
};
```

and **schema.graphql**

```
# A list of clients
type ClientList implements NodeInterface {
  # The ID of an object
  id: ID!
  clientListId: Int

  # List of clients
  clients(after: String, first: Int, before: String, last: Int): LcoClientConnection
}

# A country
type Country implements NodeInterface {
  # The ID of an object
  id: ID!
  countryId: Int
  phonePrefix: String
  name: String
  timezone: String
}

# A connection to a list of items.
type CountryConnection {
  # Information to aid in pagination.
  pageInfo: PageInfo!

  # A list of edges.
  edges: [CountryEdge]
}

# An edge in a connection.
type CountryEdge {
  # The item at the end of the edge
  node: Country

  # A cursor for use in pagination
  cursor: String
}

# A list of countries
type CountryList implements NodeInterface {
  # The ID of an object
  id: ID!
  countryListId: Int

  # Countries list
  countries(after: String, first: Int, before: String, last: Int): CountryConnection
}

# Representation of date and time in "Y-m-d H:i:s" format
scalar DateTime

# A client
type LcoClient implements NodeInterface {
  # The ID of an object
  id: ID!
  name: String
  country: Country
  address: String
  description: String
}

# A connection to a list of items.
type LcoClientConnection {
  # Information to aid in pagination.
  pageInfo: PageInfo!

  # A list of edges.
  edges: [LcoClientEdge]
}

# An edge in a connection.
type LcoClientEdge {
  # The item at the end of the edge
  node: LcoClient

  # A cursor for use in pagination
  cursor: String
}

interface NodeInterface {
  # The ID of an object
  id: ID!
}

# Information about pagination in a connection.
type PageInfo {
  # When paginating forwards, are there more items?
  hasNextPage: Boolean!

  # When paginating backwards, are there more items?
  hasPreviousPage: Boolean!

  # When paginating backwards, the cursor to continue.
  startCursor: String

  # When paginating forwards, the cursor to continue.
  endCursor: String
}

type Query {
  # Fetches an object given its ID
  node(
    # The ID of an object
    id: ID!
  ): NodeInterface
  viewer: User
  countryList: CountryList
  clientList: ClientList
}

type User implements NodeInterface {
  # The ID of an object
  id: ID!
  username: String
  userId: Int
  lastLoginDateTime: DateTime
}
```

querying for "viewer" and "countryList" types works.

I've looked on similar threads on SO but they don't solve the problem.

What am I missing?

Comment: try the query on graphiql

Comment: Have you tried to query on the main page first? Not sure if this docs will help. https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/thinking-in-relay.html#rendering